# How to put JSON chart data into pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have downloaded the har file of an interactive chart and have the datapoints in the following format:

```
'{"x":"2022-03-28T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.2615}',                             
'{"x":"2022-03-29T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.2573}',                             
'{"x":"2022-03-30T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.272}', ...
```

What would be the easiest way to convert this into a pandas dataframe?
Both the date and the value should be columns of the dataframe.

Comment: it seems you have every dictionary as string so you will have to run `json.loads()` on every element separatelly, Maybe load all to DataFrame and next use `.apply()` to run `json.loads` to get it as dictionares, and later run probably `expand()` to convert it to separated columns.eventually loading file you can set json.loads as parser but it still will need to convert dictionares to separated columns.

Comment: you have every element in `' '` so it treats them as separated items/columns but it should treat as single item/dictionary. You would have to first replace `', '` with `,` to get single string with dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that every element is in inside `' '` so it treads it as two items/columns but it should treat it as single item/doctionary. It may need to replace `', '` with `,` to have normal string with JSON which you can conver to Python dictionary using module `json`

```
text = open(filename).read()
text = text.replace("', '", ",")
```

and later you can use `io.StringIO()` to load it from text.

It needs `quotechar="'"` to read it correctly

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), names=['data', 'other'], quotechar="'")
```

next you can convert every JSON string to python dictionary

```
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(json.loads)
```

and next convert dictionary to pd.Series which you can split to columns

```
df[['x','value']] = df['data'].apply(pd.Series)
```

Finally you may remove columns `data`, `other`

```
del df['data']
del df['other']
```

---

Full working example

```
text = """'{"x":"2022-03-28T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.2615}',                             
'{"x":"2022-03-29T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.2573}',                             
'{"x":"2022-03-30T00:00:00Z"', '"value":0.272}',"""

import pandas as pd
import io
import json

#text = open(filename).read()
text = text.replace("', '", ",")
#print(text)

# read from string
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(text), names=['data', 'other'], quotechar="'")

# convert string to dictionary
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(json.loads)

# split dictionary in separated columns
df[['x','value']] = df['data'].apply(pd.Series)

# remove some columns
del df['data']
del df['other']

print(df)
```

Result:

```
                      x   value
0  2022-03-28T00:00:00Z  0.2615
1  2022-03-29T00:00:00Z  0.2573
2  2022-03-30T00:00:00Z  0.2720
```

---

You can also write some part in one line

```
df[['x','value']] = df['data'].apply(lambda item: pd.Series(json.loads(item)))
```

or split it separatelly (using `.str[index]` on dictionary)

```
df['data'] = df['data'].apply(json.loads)

df['x'] = df['data'].str['x']
df['value'] = df['data'].str['value']
```

---

**BTW:**

you may also need to convert `x` from `string` to `datetime`

```
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'])
```